# Python spectrum package installation

Tags: python, spectrum

I am trying to do some spectral analysis in python and am having trouble installing the spectrum package using easy install. I get the following errors?

Anyone have any similar trouble?

```
C:\Windows\system32>easy_install spectrum
Searching for spectrum
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/spectrum/
Best match: spectrum 0.5.6
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/spectrum/spectrum-0.5.6.tar.gz#md5=dee181b34c41f2990b4281ba4998a639
Processing spectrum-0.5.6.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\jmcneill\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-_5or57\spectrum-0.5.6\setup.cfg
Running spectrum-0.5.6\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\jmcneill\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-_5or57\spectru
m-0.5.6\egg-dist-tmp-op3lmq
Cannot export initmydpss: symbol not defined
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes same here.

Look in the temporary installation directory (C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp) of the package and add simply in the `mydpss.c` file:

```
initmydpss(void) { }
```

I know this is not very clean but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I cannot find the temporary directory that is created 
 
c:\users...\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-_5or57\spectru
m-0.5.6\egg-dist-tmp-op3lmq 
 
I can navigate to c:\users...\appdata\local\temp, but the rest of the path is not there.

Comment: Okay. I found the following link...
https://www.assembla.com/spaces/PySpectrum/tickets/1-mingw-compilation-issue-under-windows#/activity/ticket:

Comment: spectrum was updated on github and pip with version 0.6.0 that adds the  initmydpss(void) { } trick in the c code. Hoping this helps.